# Meaning of "crossing asynchronous boundaries"

Tags: asynchronous, akka, streaming

From Akka Documentation, [Pipelining and Parallelism](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-parallelism.html)

> Akka Streams processing stages (be it simple operators on Flows and
>   Sources or graph junctions) are “fused” together and executed
>   sequentially by default. This avoids the overhead of events crossing
>   asynchronous boundaries but limits the flow to execute at most one
>   stage at any given time.

What is the meaning of **events crossing asynchronous boundaries** ?

The same term is also frequently used in [A Tale of Two Monix Stream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JFbYQGG2Nb4) and corresponding [slides](https://speakerdeck.com/alexandru/a-tale-of-two-monix-streams-1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you materialize a stream, the `ActorMaterializer` decides how to run the different stages. By default, all stages run sequentially inside the same actor behind the scenes. This is to avoid the thread context switch overhead that will happen if each stage would be run in a different actor.

When you use the `async` operator on a stage, you are telling the materializer that you want to create an asynchronous boundary at that point. That means that stage will run in its own actor behind the scenes. Depending on the scenario this might impact performance since events will be crossing asynchronous boundaries.

For example:

```
Source(List("A","B","C "))
  .map(x => x.toLowerCase)
  .async
  .map(x => x.toUpperCase)
  .map(x => x.trim)
  .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

This stream will run the stage `map(x => x.toLowerCase)` in a different actor than the stages `map(x => x.toUpperCase)` and `map(x => x.trim)`. These last two will run inside the same actor.

One last thing to mention is that asynchronous boundaries also allow to  process events in parallel inside the stream. Each async boundary can process events independently since they run in different actors (as long as there is demand from downstream). In this simple scenario, "B" can be processed at `map(x => x.toLowerCase)` concurrently with "A" being processed at `map(x => x.toUpperCase)` and `map(x => x.trim)`.

I hope this helps understanding a bit more about how streams work.

Comment: wonderful, thanks for the example, this really helps to grasp the concept

Comment: Can you please confirm that if stage2 is dependent on stage1, we should **not** add an asynchronous boundary in between?